# jquery append element id is not identified

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I am trying to dynamically append a textarea to a div using jquery. While the basic code worked, I suspect there is some issue. This is because when I try to return the width of the textarea using its id, it returns a null. That means the id is not set properly as the textarea can be seen in the page. Here is a part of the my jquery code

```
var form = $('<form/>',{"id" : "AnswerBox"}).appendTo($("#unanswered"));

$('<textarea/>').attr({
    "rows":5,
    "id" : "AnswerBoxArea",
    "name" : "answer"               
}).appendTo('form');
```

Now if I do an alert

```
alert($("#AnswerBoxArea").width());
```

It returns a NULL, can't understand why. Any help?

The problem I don't think is not account of setting of width. It seems more on setting of the element id. As if I do a alert($("#AnswerBoxArea").attr('id')) it returns undefined

Nothing seems to be working. I am providing the detaied code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

$.ajax({
        url: "myteacher.php",
        dataType: "json",

        success: function(response){
                        console.log(response);

                      $("#unanswered").append("<p style='text-align:justify; border-radius: 5px; background-color:rgb(220,220,220); padding: 5px'>"+response.qtext+"</p>");
                            $("#unanswered").append('<form method = "POST" style = "padding:5px; margin:5px;" id="AnswerBox">');
                            $("#unanswered form").append('<textarea rows="5" id="AnswerBoxArea" name="answer">');
                            $("#unanswered form").append('<br><input type="submit" value="Answer" id="AnsTextQ">');


        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(jqXHR.status+",  " + jqXHR.statusText+",  "+textStatus+",  "+errorThrown);
        }
    });
    $(".AnswerBoxArea").css("width", $("#AnsBoxDiv").width()-30);
    $(".AnswerBoxArea").css("max-width", $("#AnsBoxDiv").width()-30);
    alert($("#unanswered").attr("id"));
    alert($("#AnswerBoxArea").attr("id"));
```

});

Is it a problem of the scope of the variable. The id is local and it cannot be accessed?

Comment: Nothing wrong with your posted code https://jsfiddle.net/7js4v2nc/. Do you have any errors in the console? What does the rendered html look like? How/When/Where are you calling the alert?

Comment: The alert is only a check and nothing else. I believe the id is not getting set. Any reason why?

Comment: Check #unanswered element exists or not. Check for any errors in console. Check with @Jasen fiddle its working fine.

Comment: alert does return the ID AnswerBoxArea on https://jsfiddle.net/7js4v2nc/

Comment: I have given the more detailed code with some modification. Any help? I still get an undefined id

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried css in order to get/set width?

```
Use jQuery's css method like this:

.css("width", width)

or this, if you plan on setting more attributes:

.css({"width":width})
```

Comment: no reason that using `css()` would work if `width()` doesn't